# How to plot legend with diff color correspond to diff value in matplotlib python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, colorbar

I am trying to plot subarea of landuse dataset, I want to get a legend like in the picture. I am using `plt.imshow()` to plot img, the input is 2D array, the value of array is land use code.

How can I get a legend like this:

[image: legends]

Answer (score 0):

You can add proxy artists to a plot as shown in the [matplotlib legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists).

Example code from the guide:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])

plt.show()
```

which gives
[image]

Not sure how to get a legend title though.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clearly, I want to extract color from img and according to those colors, get the legend

Comment: How do you know which label the color in the image corresponds to? If you just want the colors, just run a for loop over all the unique colors in the image and create a patch for each?

Comment: I know how to solve it now.
1st, set your own colormap
2nd, based on colormap set legend patches